# inserting data into sql table using foreach php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a form, that sends multiple seats to a php file. I created a foreach loop to insert each seat into sql. For some reason i am able to get all the information i need to send it but it wont insert.

I dont know if it has something to do with foreign keys? But what i want to do is show what email selected what seat. I also want to disable each seat when it is sent to sql.

[sql side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0SEL.png)

This is my output.

```
    You are currently in database admin.


admin@airways.com
1A
1B
1C
Data added successfully.
Back to seating.
```

This is my flightselect.php

```
            <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
    include_once 'includes/functions.php';
    sec_session_start();

if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    $logged = 'in';
} else {
    $logged = 'out';
}
                $username = $_SESSION['username'];
                echo  '<p>You are currently '.$logged. ' database '.$username. '.</p><br>';

                $getemail = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT email FROM members WHERE username = '$username' ");
                $email = '';
                while($gear = mysqli_fetch_array( $getemail )) {
                    echo $gear['email'];
                    $email = $gear['email'];
                } 

                echo $gear."<br>";

    if(isset($_POST['seatme'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['flight'])){
            foreach($_POST['flight'] as $key=>$selected){
                echo $selected."<br>";
                $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO seating (seat_id, email, flight_id) 
                                                    VALUES ('$selected', '$gear', '1' )");
            }
        }
    }
        echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.";
        echo "<br/><a href='user.php'>Back to seating.</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Please include code instead of screen-shots.

Comment: What error message are you getting or what evidence are you seeing that your code is not working?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Kind of odd you do the same query twice in a row. Transposing the name and values doesn't really make a different table insert ;)

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text or a weak hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: its not sending the query to sql i assume. becuase the values arent getting inserted.

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are different software packages produced by different companies. Even if all of them implement SQL, they extend it in different ways and sometimes they use different syntax conventions that render the queries incompatible between them. Please use only the tags that match the software you are using.

Comment: @tadman FWIW `The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when mysqli API was introduced and should not be used in new code` I disagree. Procedural code isn't bad and is still written a lot. OO Code isn't the be-all end-all

Comment: @Xatenev I'm not arguing against procedural code in general, just the `mysqli` procedural interface. You're *always* one missing `i` away from hours of frustration, confusion, and anguish. It's also way more verbose as you have to prefix everything with `mysqli_blah_blah_something($db, ...)` instead of just `$db->something(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a brackets after the VALUES keyword...

```
       if (!mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO seating (seat_id, email, flight_id) 
                                   VALUES ('$selected', '$gear', '1' )"))  {
                 printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
       }
```

You should also learn about prepared statements as they make your SQL more secure.

Comment: I just tried what you said, it didnt work, the data was not passed into sql. could it be becuase of foreign keys ? or something?

Comment: The value `$selected` is defined as numeric on the database (field seat_id) and yet your trying to pass '3B'.

Comment: I just changed my sql to varchar50. then tried submitting again. it still didnt work. i updated my code to how it looks as well.

Comment: I've just updated the code, see if it generates anything useful (an error would be very helpful)

Comment: i updated my output, but nothing useful shows up to the code. i have no idea why it isnt working.